# Asus nexus 7 (2012) and Cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, nexus-7

I've grown confused by the various nexus 7 models as I want to try cyanogenmod on my tablet. So I wonder:

Is there any software difference between the asus nexus 7 tablet and the google nexus 7 one, or are they one of the same, meaning I can use the regular cyanogenmod google nexus 7 ROM for my asus nexus 7? And what about 2012 vs 2013 beyond hardware (camera at back on the 2013) versions in therms of getting the correct ROM for my 2012 model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an Asus one and a Google one: both the Nexus 7 models are Asus-Google collaborations. All Nexus devices are design collaborations between Google and another device manufacturer (Asus, Samsung, or LG).

That said, the two models are completely different, with different SoCs, screens, and cameras. The original Nexus 7 (aka *nakasi*) has a slightly-over-720p screen, powered by a Tegra 3, and only one camera. The 2013 model (aka *razor*) has a 1920x1200 screen, two cameras, and a Snapdragon SoC. **ROMs are not compatible between the two.**

Comment: So 2013 ROM can't go for 2012 model, makes sense, but google nexus 7 and asus nexus 7 2012 is the same thing, and thus I can safely get a ROM that say it goes for either?

Comment: Not quite. "Google Nexus 7" and "Asus Nexus 7" are the same thing, and aren't clear about whether it's the 2012 or 2013 model. If it doesn't specifically say "2012" or "nakasi", you should check.

Comment: Aha, so the only thing I need to worry about is if the ROM is for 2012 or 2013 model, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 2):

Dan is correct, but what also needs to be known is whether it is 3G/WiFi (tilapia 2012, deb 2013) or just WiFi(grouper 2012, flo 2013). The 2 models can't use the ROMs for the other, meaning you can't use the 2012 3G ROM on the 2012 WiFi model and etc.

*the above in parenthesis are the names for different models and years*

So there is actually 4 different models each with their own ROMs.

The XDA forums have the largest amount of ROMs for the Nexus 7's. There are many to choose from.

Comment: Mine is just a 2012 version with WIFI, so a Grouper. But thanks for additional heads-up!

Comment: @Sharain here is the link to the XDA forum for the index/repo of  Grouper ROMs, this was updated 3/14. You should find one you like. While there look up MultiROM Manager, multiboot the N7 with as many Roms you want, which makes it super easy/faster to figure out which ROM you like.